# The best way to get from user two dimensional array in javaFX

Tags: user-interface, matrix, javafx

I need to get matrix from user. Which of the JavaFX features is the most useful? Grid with (m*n) textFields or TableView? The thing is, it is hard to represent TableView with variable number of columns.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question.  How big is the array?  What will the array and it's UI representation be used for?  Is the array size fixed or variable?  Have you already tried to solve this problem and, if so, what are your issues with that attempted solution?  Do you have any code for your attempted solution that you could include in your question?

Comment: array size is variable, maximum 7 * 7, and I have no ideas for solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a TextArea

```
public class Matrix extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextArea txt = new TextArea();

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);

        txt.setOnKeyReleased(t-> {
            int i = 0;
            String[] rows = txt.getText().split("\n");
            for (String row: rows){
                String[] cols = row.split("\\s+");
                int j = 0;
                for (String col : cols)
                    grid.add(new Text(col), j++, i);
                i++;
            }
        });


        VBox root = new VBox(txt, grid);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]

I'd probably do some better formatting:)  You could also use a TextField but split with brackets or something.